# 9patch drawable or separate image in each drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, nine-patch

Is it better to have separate image in each drawable folder (hdpi, ldpi, ...) or use 9patch drawable?
I want to use 9patch drawable for different screen size but I am not sure which is better. I know that 9patch drawable is better because it we can use only one image instead of several image in  each drawable folder.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "image".

Comment: image that I set in imageview

Comment: As a background or source? If the source, you should definitely not use 9patch. 9patch is for assets like a shaded background or something which can be easily scaled on various densities.

Answer (score 1):

It seams like you're misunderstanding the intent of [Nine-Patch Drawables](https://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch):

> A NinePatch is a PNG image in which you can define stretchable regions that Android scales when content within the View exceeds the normal image bounds.

There's no correlation to the screen density. If you're not using very simple graphics, you might need to add the nine-patch files to *each drawable folder* anyway.